# An argument named "vpc_id" is not expected here

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I'm new to terraform.. I'm getting the below error when I run terraform plan,

```
Error: Unsupported argument
> │
on 4_data_vpc.tf line 6, in data "aws_subnets" "subnets":
6:   vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default_vpc.id
> │
An argument named "vpc_id" is not expected here.
```

This is the data_vpc.tf file

```
data "aws_vpc" "default_vpc" {
  default = true
}

# subnet list in the "default" VPC
# The "default" VPC has all "public subnets"
data "aws_subnet_ids" "default_public" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.default_vpc.id}"
}
```

I've updated aws_subnet_ids to aws_subnets as aws_subnet_ids data source has been deprecated

provider.tf file

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "us-east-1"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "dev"
}
```

securityGroups.tf

```
# Security Group:
resource "aws_security_group" "jenkins_server" {
  name        = "jenkins_server"
  description = "Jenkins Server: created by Terraform for [dev]"

  # legacy name of VPC ID
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.default_vpc.id}"

  tags {
    Name = "jenkins_server"
    env  = "dev"
  }
}

###############################################################################
# ALL INBOUND
###############################################################################

# ssh
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "jenkins_server_from_source_ingress_ssh" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.jenkins_server.id}"
  cidr_blocks       = ["<Your Public IP>/32", "172.0.0.0/8"]
  description       = "ssh to jenkins_server"
}

# web
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "jenkins_server_from_source_ingress_webui" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 8080
  to_port           = 8080
  protocol          = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.jenkins_server.id}"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  description       = "jenkins server web"
}

# JNLP
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "jenkins_server_from_source_ingress_jnlp" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 33453
  to_port           = 33453
  protocol          = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.jenkins_server.id}"
  cidr_blocks       = ["172.31.0.0/16"]
  description       = "jenkins server JNLP Connection"
}

###############################################################################
# ALL OUTBOUND
###############################################################################

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "jenkins_server_to_other_machines_ssh" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.jenkins_server.id}"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  description       = "allow jenkins servers to ssh to other machines"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "jenkins_server_outbound_all_80" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 80
  to_port           = 80
  protocol          = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.jenkins_server.id}"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  description       = "allow jenkins servers for outbound yum"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "jenkins_server_outbound_all_443" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 443
  protocol          = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.jenkins_server.id}"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  description       = "allow jenkins servers for outbound yum"
}
```

When I declare a variable vpc_id in the data_vpc.tf file and run terraform plan then the terminal is asking me to enter a value.

```
var.vpc_id
  Enter a value:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using [aws_subnets](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.43.0/docs/data-sources/subnet), to add `vpc_id`, you have to use `filter` block:

```
data "aws_subnets" "subnets" {
   filter {
     name   = "vpc-id"
     values = [data.aws_vpc.default_vpc.id]
   }
}
```